# How to insert the dynamic value in for i in range Python

Tags: python

```
def reshape_data(actor_data):
    data_dict = {}

    max_num_actors = len(actor_data)

    for i in range(max_num_actors):
        col_num = i + 1
        data_dict[f'Cast {col_num}'] = [actor_data[i][0]]
        data_dict[f'Char {col_num}'] = [actor_data[i][1]]
        data_dict[f'Role {col_num}'] = [actor_data[i][2]]

    for i in range(max_num_actors, 100):
        col_num = i + 1
        data_dict[f'Cast {col_num}'] = ['N/A']
        data_dict[f'Char {col_num}'] = ['N/A']
        data_dict[f'Role {col_num}'] = ['N/A']

    actors_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
    
    return actors_df
```

My Probles is the number "100" i want to get the actual number of max_num_actors.. if the file on excel column and row is blank then from headers to row put an "N/A".

this i made the change but the FILL is not working. but when using int then its working.

```
def reshape_data(actor_data):
    data_dict = {}

    max_num_actors = len(actor_data)
    variable = max_num_actors

    for i in range(max_num_actors):
        col_num = i + 1
        data_dict[f'Cast {col_num}'] = [actor_data[i][0]]
        data_dict[f'Char {col_num}'] = [actor_data[i][1]]
        data_dict[f'Role {col_num}'] = [actor_data[i][2]]

    for i in range(max_num_actors, variable):
        col_num = i + 1
        data_dict[f'Cast {col_num}'] = ['N/A']
        data_dict[f'Char {col_num}'] = ['N/A']
        data_dict[f'Role {col_num}'] = ['N/A']

    actors_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
    
    return actors_df
```

Comment: If the spreadsheet only has 50 rows, why isn't that the "actual number"? Where do you think the other 50 rows would be in Excel?

Comment: excel rows its unlimited bro

Comment: Right, so where do you think the actual max should come from?

Comment: i already make a 1 more variable for max_num_actors to get the value pass  100 but it gives me some error.

Comment: Please show what you tried and the error + traceback.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. If you don't want to hard-code a number like 100, where should it come from?

Comment: i updated my code. there is no error at all. but the code is not working when creating it as variable.

Comment: When `variable == max_num_actors`, the second loop doesn't do anything. Why are you using the same value for both?

Comment: Maybe `variable = max_num_actors + 50` to add 50 extra places?

Comment: Newbee. is not working...

Comment: If you don't explain what the expected result is, I can't help you.

Comment: Why isn't `len(actor_data)` the actual number of actors? It's the number of rows in the spreadsheet, why do you need more?

Comment: im getting this when i use that. 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I don't understand. It's what you're doing with `max_num_actors = len(actor_data)`, you didn't get an error there.

Comment: this is for adding value for each single data. i already ask chatgpt but it give me fallhopes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254684/discussion-between-barmar-and-malandi).

Comment: @Malandi The number of rows in an Excel spreadsheet is **not** unlimited

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def reshape_data(actor_data, max_cols=3):
    data_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for i, (cast, char, role) in enumerate(actor_data):
        col_num = i % max_cols + 1
        data_dict[f'Cast {col_num}'].append(cast or 'N/A')
        data_dict[f'Char {col_num}'].append(char or 'N/A')
        data_dict[f'Role {col_num}'].append(role or 'N/A')

    # Fill out the last row if necessary
    last = len(actor_data) % max_cols
    if last != 0:
        for col_num in range(last+1, max_cols):
            data_dict[f'Cast {col_num}'].append('N/A')
            data_dict[f'Char {col_num}'].append('N/A')
            data_dict[f'Role {col_num}'].append('N/A')

    actors_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
    return actors_df
```

Comment: the headers and row is limited into 3 only. it should be more..

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted. You kept using 3 in the chat.

Comment: If it can vary, make that a parameter to the function.

Comment: it should be more pls help

Comment: Just add a variable like `num_cols`, and then replace all the 3 with `num_cols`, and `4` with `num_cols + 1`.

Comment: Do you really need everything spelled out for you? Are you a programmer or not? There's only so much free work I'm going to do for you.

Comment: sorry bro cant understand by the way thank you...

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the variable

Comment: ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: I'm going to sleep. You deb ug it.

Comment: going to sleep now bytheway thanks.. im working withis for the past 2 days now..